Body switching is mainstream
I have in my mind a scene in a film, which I thought was from 2009's "Surrogates". But having watched that recently I realise that I am wrong.
A premise of the film is that some sort of body switching is de riguer (though possibly exclusively for the rich elite?).
There is a scene where a character goes to visit another well-off businessman at work, and discovers someone who looks like a personal trainer sitting in the main chair at the desk, working, whilst someone who looks like a fat-cat manager is on a treadmill running.
The personal-trainer body is currently being occupied by the mind of the manager, whilst the manager body is currently being occupied by the mind of the personal trainer who does the unpleasant running experience for his client.
What film is this?
I have a vague feeling that it might be a Schwarznegger vehicle, and that someone putting their hand in a vat of something damaging is a plot point in the climax?

Yep, that's the one, Walt. Thanks!

It's XChange: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242150/
Treadmill scene is in the trailer, no less: 


